# JSON Schema to represent a name and value with value constrained by name

Tags: jsonschema

I have the following JSON snippets which are all valid

```
"units": { "name": "EU", "value": "Grams" }
"units": { "name": "EU", "value": "Kilograms" }
"units": { "name": "US", "value": "Ounces" }
"units": { "name": "US", "value": "Pounds" }
```

The name values can be EU and US and the valid value value should depend on the name value.

It's easy to use JSON Schema enums for both these properties, but can I enforce the additional constraint using JSON Schema?

I would consider changing the overall schema so that there is a parent child relationship between a name object and value object, but ideally this would be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to crack it using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ to work though an example. The following schema provides the solution:

```
"units": { 
    "type":"object",
    "oneOf": [ {
      "properties": {
        "name": { "enum": [ "EU" ] },
        "value": { "enum" : ["Grams", "Kilograms"]}}}, {
      "properties": {
        "name": { "enum": [ "US" ] },
        "value": { "enum": ["Ounces", "Pounds"]}}}]
}
```